# geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: Non-successful status code 502

Tags: python, geopy

I use geopy to convet a coordinate into an address in order to get the name of the country and this is my code :

```
   def convert_latandlong_to_address(self):
       
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="miz")
        location = geolocator.reverse(self.lat+","+self.lng,timeout=10)
        address = location.raw['address']
        return address
```

it works fine but i realized that after several requests it returns 502 error :

```
geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: Non-successful status code 502
```

and this is full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py", line 360, in _call_geocoder
    result = self.adapter.get_json(url, timeout=timeout, headers=req_headers)
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py", line 373, in get_json
    resp = self._request(url, timeout=timeout, headers=headers)
  File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py", line 401, in _request
    raise AdapterHTTPError(
geopy.adapters.AdapterHTTPError: Non-successful status code 502

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
        response = self.handle_exception(exc)
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
        self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
        raise exc
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
        response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/admin1/mizbanproject/location/preferlocation/api/views.py", line 15, in get_prefer_locations
        address = location_obj.convert_latandlong_to_address()
      File "/home/admin1/mizbanproject/location/preferlocation/api/utils.py", line 27, in convert_latandlong_to_address
        location = geolocator.reverse(self.lat+","+self.lng,timeout=10)
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/nominatim.py", line 359, in reverse
        return self._call_geocoder(url, callback, timeout=timeout)
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py", line 378, in _call_geocoder
        self._adapter_error_handler(error)
      File "/home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py", line 392, in _adapter_error_handler
        raise exc_cls(str(error)) from error
    geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: Non-successful status code 502
```

and after a few seconds or minutes when i run the code again it works i can't figure out what causes this problem and how can i prevent it ?

Comment: i'm having the same problem right now, GeocoderServiceError: Non-successful status code 502 after a single query

Comment: Yep, I'm having the same problem too

Comment: Down here as well. It worked for about 15 minutes a couple hours ago, but crashed again.

Comment: According to Nominatim Usage Policy , heavy requests are not allowed and only 1 request per second is allowed !i switched to geoapify and it works fine.